# Using Rule to Insert Into Secondary Table Auto-Increments Sequence

Tags: postgresql, rules

To automatically add a column in a second table to tie it to the first table via a unique index, I have a rule such as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE auto_insert AS ON INSERT TO user DO ALSO
INSERT INTO lastlogin (id) VALUES (NEW.userid);
```

This works fine if *user.userid* is an integer. However, if it is a sequence (e.g., type **serial** or **bigserial**), what is inserted into table *lastlogin* is the next sequence id. So this command:

```
INSERT INTO user (username) VALUES ('john');
```

would insert column [1, 'john', ...] into *user* but column [2, ...] into *lastlogin*. The following 2 workarounds do work except that the second one consumes twice as many serials since the sequence is still auto-incrementing:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE auto_insert AS ON INSERT TO user DO ALSO
INSERT INTO lastlogin (id) VALUES (lastval());

CREATE OR REPLACE RULE auto_insert AS ON INSERT TO user DO ALSO
INSERT INTO lastlogin (id) VALUES (NEW.userid-1);
```

Unfortunately, the workarounds do not work if I'm inserting multiple rows:

```
INSERT INTO user (username) VALUES ('john'), ('mary');
```

The first workaround would use the same id, and the second workaround is all kind of screw-up.

Is it possible to do this via postgresql rules or should I simply do the 2nd insertion into *lastlogin* myself or use a row trigger? Actually, I think the row trigger would also auto-increment the sequence when I access *NEW.userid*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forget rules altogether. They're **bad**.

Triggers are way better for you. And in 99% of cases when someone thinks he needs a rule. Try this:

```
create table users (
  userid serial primary key,
  username text
);

create table lastlogin (
  userid int primary key references users(userid),
  lastlogin_time timestamp with time zone
);

create or replace function lastlogin_create_id() returns trigger as $$
  begin
    insert into lastlogin (userid) values (NEW.userid);
    return NEW;
  end;
$$
language plpgsql volatile;

create trigger lastlogin_create_id
  after insert on users for each row execute procedure lastlogin_create_id();
```

Then:

```
insert into users (username) values ('foo'),('bar');

select * from users;
```

```
 userid | username 
--------+----------
      1 | foo
      2 | bar
(2 rows)
```

```
select * from lastlogin;
```

```
 userid | lastlogin_time 
--------+----------------
      1 | 
      2 | 
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks. The trigger works. I'm curious as to why the rule auto-increments the sequence but not the trigger.

Comment: A rule woks on query level, not on data level. They're very complicated and easy to do wrong. I think they're mostly useful only for creating updateable views.